# How do I work player health In Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am unsure how to make a health system for a class player to get killed after getting hit three times. Can someone please help? I am using Python 2.7 to code.
I currently have

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, opponents):
   player.kill()
```

and i was considering using a variable

```
player.HP = 3
```

but it won't die!

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, opponents):
   player.HP -1
   if player.HP == 0:
      player.kill
```

but, like i said, it won't die but the code works. It was killing until i added the new system, and now it won't. Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably start with smaller scale projects than a full-blown graphical game. Your error is that `player.HP - 1` doesn't change anything. You have to do `player.HP = player.HP - 1` or `player.HP -= 1`. This is basic Python stuff, and it's going to be painful learning this way. Start simpler to get the basics down pat, then move up.

Comment: Right. And somehow, you managed to make a game without understanding how variable work. Take it or leave it, but my advice is to start smaller and simpler  - not necessarily *easy* -  but it seems counterproductive to muck around with graphics and sprites if you don't understand the basics. I'm not trying to be mean here or anything, it is just advice. You should check out the Intro to Interactive Programming in Python coursera class from Rice university.

Comment: It is hard to help you after a statement such as "it won't die but the code works" since the code clearly does not "work" as you would expect it to. It is also a rare case of a question providing too little code to make much sense of. You should provide at least the names of your methods, the relevant code piece and the expected outcome. Despite all these deficiencies the first comment already got you the answer (very probably).

Comment: Although I don't disagree with what the others have said, I am not sure why the question was down voted. The OP stated his question and provided his attempted code. A newbie doesn't deserve a down vote. Let's not punish him for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga said in a comment, you need to assign the decremented value of player.HP or else, you are doing subtraction and throwing away the value.  You need to change:

```
player.HP -1
```

to

```
player.HP -= 1
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self, val):
...     self.val = val
...   def decrement(self):
...     self.val - 1              # <- Does not reassign decremented value
...     print self.val
...
>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.decrement()
10
>>> a.decrement()
10
>>> a.decrement()
10
>>> a.decrement()
10
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self, val):
...     self.val = val
...   def decrement(self):
...     self.val -= 1             # <- Does reassign value
...     print self.val
...
>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.decrement()
9
>>> a.decrement()
8
>>> a.decrement()
7
>>> a.decrement()
6
```

Comment: To someone new to Python, that demonstration is a little bit difficult to understand. What might have been easier is to simply assign `a` to 10, then do `a-1`, and notice that `a` is still 10, then try `a-=1` and show that a is now 9.